# Follow changes in AD via PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have written a scripts in PowerShell, which follow about changes made in the AD, by the cmdlet `Get-ADObject`:

```
$Date = Get-Date
$FixedDate.AddHours(13)
Get-ADObject -Filter "whenchanged -gt $Date.Date" -Properties  sAMAccountName, whenCreated, whenChanged |
    select |
    Format-Table -Property sAMAccountName,whenCreated,whenChanged  -AutoSize
```

The script above only can follow about the changes in the AD, but I want that the script also can tell me which user made the change.

How can we do this?

Comment: Note that a filter `"whenchanged -gt $Date.Date"` is not going to work, because PowerShell doesn't expand properties inside a string. You need to put the date in a subexpression (`"whenchanged -gt $($Date.Date)"`). Also, where does this useless empty `select` come from that I keep seeing lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to do can't be done unless you enable auditing for the change of Active Directory objects. You can do this inside GPO and also inside SACL. Once enabled you need to apply it to the AD.

As far as the script is: We first get the Date of when we want to check the AD for any objects that where changed. I like doing `Get-ADObject -Filter ‘whenChanged -gt $Date’ | Group-Object objectclass`. This will tell me what has changed, from Accounts, Groups, Policy, etc.

Now we can use the select statment to narrow the results down. If it was the Account that was deleted we can use the example you gave.

```
$Date = [datetime]”3/19/2017"
#Get-ADObject -Filter ‘whenChanged -gt $Date’ | Group-Object objectclass

Get-ADObject -Filter 'whenChanged -gt $Date' -Properties *| 
select Name, sAMAccountName, whenChanged, whenCreated | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

We can also add the switch `-IncludeDeletedObjects` = retrieve deleted objects

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'whenChanged -gt $Date' -Properties * -IncludeDeletedObjects | 
select Name, sAMAccountName, whenChanged, whenCreated | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Without Auditing turned ON, getting who did it will not be possible.

If Auditing is turned on correctly it should display in the Event Viewer and look for the ID  `4726`.
We can use the following PowerShell script:

```
Get-Eventlog -Log Security -After $Date -Newest 10| Where {$_.EventID -eq 4726}
```

Event ID can have a lot of options, but if we do not know what happen to that user or object. We can run:

```
Get-Eventlog -Log Security -After $Date -Newest 10 -Message "*A user account*"
```

Some usefull Event ID for AD Audit:

```
Event ID 4720 - A user account was created.
Event ID 4722 - A user account was enabled.
Event ID 4726 - A user account was deleted.
Event ID 4738 - A user account was changed.

Event ID 5141 – A directory service object was deleted.
Event ID 5136 – A directory service object was modified.
Event ID 5139 – A directory service object was moved.
Event ID 5141 – A directory service object was deleted.
```

Comment: Hi, The audit enabled, but I still can't get who changed any in the AD.
Does there is a command which can do this ?